# Snowflake query to pull code description from table 2 which has multiple code in single cell in table 1

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with column that has values in each cell like table 1

### Table2 and Table 1

| Code | Codedescription |
| --- | --- |
| #18 | low credit |
| #20 | unable to verify residence |
| #8 | insufficient balance |

| NAME | CODE |
| --- | --- |
| Anand | #20 #18 |
| Riya | #8 |

I have another table that has description for these individual codes like

with code and code description as two columns in table 2.

Now I need to pull the code description for each value in table 1.
The rows which has single code has no issues but the rows that has #24 #18 this format has issue to pull records.Any help please.

| Name | CodeDescription |
| --- | --- |
| Anand | unable to verify residence, insufficient balance |
| Riya | insufficient balance |

I tried using split_part function to split #20 #18 to
`#20` as code1
`#18` as code2
and tried to join with table 2 on code.
But I couldn’t retrieve description for both #20 and #18 as new column with concatenated description like

`Low credit, Unable to verify residence as new column` as new column

Comment: After you do your `split_part` and join, you likely want to reaggregate the data with something like `listagg` to create a concatenated string.

Comment: Thanks Mike.Tried using listagg but it’s concatenating the entire code description for all person in each row.can we use group within and order by names or any unique id while using listagg?

Comment: Hi - I’d start by fixing your broken data model and stop holding multiple values in the same field

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the input.Will check if this can be addressed.For now my source server has multiple values and I have to go with this .Is there any other option to solve the above scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [split_to_table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table)

```
SELECT A.NAME, B.VALUE AS CODE, table1.Codedescription
FROM Table2 A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT NAME, VALUE
  FROM Table2, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(CODE, ' ')
) B ON A.NAME = B.NAME
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON B.VALUE = table1.Code
ORDER BY A.NAME, B.VALUE;
```

Edit:

In order to group the descriptions for a name use listagg

```
SELECT Name, LISTAGG(CODEDESCRIPTION, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CODEDESCRIPTION) AS CODEDESCRIPTION
FROM (
SELECT A.NAME, B.VALUE AS CODE, table1.Codedescription
FROM Table2 A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT NAME, VALUE
  FROM Table2, LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(CODE, ' ')
) B ON A.NAME = B.NAME
LEFT JOIN table1 ON B.VALUE = table1.Code
ORDER BY A.NAME, B.VALUE
)
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: This code works but for some reason its not assigning description for few names

Comment: Probably there is a discrepancy in the data. Could you tell me the name , code  and description from table1 and table2

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
SELECT NAME,LISTAGG(CODEDESCRIPTION ,' '  ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NAME )
FROM
(
SELECT TABLE2.NAME NAME, TABLE2.CODE CODE,TABLE1.CODEDESCRIPTION  CODEDESCRIPTION
FROM 
TABLE1 INNER JOIN
( SELECT * FROM 
TABLE2,LATERAL split_to_table(TABLE2.CODE,' ')
)TABLE2
ON TABLE2.VALUE=TABLE1.CODE)
GROUP BY NAME
;
```

Comment: Thank you ,same as before this is giving extra reasons for the same person who has only 2 of the denial codes assigned